# need to add css,js files inside the modules folder CI hmvc

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on a CodeIgniter - HMVC

**What I know:**
    *is I should not create assets like css,js,images inside the application folder in codeigniter, but I have a necessity for it.*

**What I am trying to achieve is : **
   to create a standalone module and trying to use it in another project. In that case, I really need to add the necessary css,js,images files into the modules folder it self.

**The Error I get is:**

> You don't have permission to access /v7-bitbucket/application/modules/some_modle/assets/bootstrap.min.css on this server.

How do I overcome this?
Please advice.
Thanks.

Comment: Your application folder is inside or outsdie web root?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I can think of for you to access this data.

The first one is using an htaccess and a custom rule, which redirects certain files to inside the other directory. This way, the user will still have access to only certain specific files outside of the public HTML folder.

The second option is to use PHP and render the content of the file in custom tags.
Ex: Instead of entering `<link href="<?= $path ?>">`, you would do `<style><?= file_get_contents($path) ?></style>`. This would be harder to cache, and a bit harder to implement for images.